# JavaScript function to change global variable value

Tags: javascript, debugging, animation, parameters, global-variables

I'm doing an animation and I'm trying to control what is displayed and what is not displayed.
To do this, I'm putting IF conditions so if a var x = 0 it's not displayed, if var x = 1 it displays.

I made it work so far (when I assign the var x = 1 it works), it's just the statement to change the value that doesn't work, I guess for scope reasons but I'm hopping someone can give me a hand.

The idea is that if you click on "black" it will display some speakers.

Many thanks in advance.

```
    window.onload = init;

    function init() {
    var white = paper.rect( 740, 575, 20, 20);
    var black = paper.rect( 770, 575, 20, 20);
    var yellow = paper.rect( 40, 575, 20, 20);
    var audio = new Audio('sound.mp3');
    var displaySpeakers = 0;


    function displayFunction() {
    displaySpeakers = 1;
    }

    function speakers() {
    if (displaySpeakers == 0)
        return;
 // otherwise this function displays the speakers
     }

    speakers(); // this calls the speakers.

    black.attr({fill: "black", stroke: "none"}).click(function(){displayFunction();});

 // Black should display the speakers
    };
```

Comment: You never call `speakers()` in the posted code, maybe we need some more context.

Comment: I filtered some of my code that is irrelevant. I call the speakers on the fourth line from the bottom, then click on black should change the var displaySpeakers to 1 and speakers should display. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: If all the code is placed inside `init()` (as it looks like), there should not be troubles with `displaySpeakers`. Or are there more missing/misplaced curly braces in the post?

Answer (score 1):

As Teemu said you don't call the `speakers` function. You call it once after the `onload` event, but when you click on `black`, you just change the value of  `displaySpeakers` to 1.

The `speakers` function is not called so it cannot know that the value changed. All you have to do is calling `speakers` into the `displayFunction` function or directly into the `click` function.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. speaker() has to run again each time I "update" the value. Therefore running speaker() multiple times too so if I put the value of displaySpeakers to 0 and run it, it won't appear again but the previous run will still be displayed. This addresses another problem... any ideas?

Comment: @MTTPC With no more code I can't tell you exactly, maybe you should embed your speaker HTML code into a div with an id and then call the JQuery [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function.